# Google Custom Search Engine - Edit the URLs in SERP

Tags: google-custom-search

Good evening, I'm working with Google Custom Search Engine: https://cse.google.it/cse/ and I need to add, only for some URLs (in total 10 URLs) a parameter at the end of each search results URL. For example: if the domain is www.dominio-test.com then the URL to show is www.dominio-test.com/123456 the CSE searches on the web without restriction.

The code I use is the following:

```
    <script async src = "https://cse.google.com/cse.js cx=014431187084467459449:v2cmjgvgjr0"> </script>

    <div class = "gcse-search"> </div>
```

I thought of proceeding with reading the DOM with getElementsByClassName (), extracting the content and adding it to a variable, at this point add the if / else / replace controls and output again.

But I don't know how to proceed, can you please support me?
Thanks and good job

Answer (score 0):

Search Element callbacks might work for you: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#callbacks